# How to know if how many node hours I have used on a Google Cloud ML for prediction?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I tried to find out how to get the node hour usage of my Google Cloud ML Prediction API, but didn't find any. Is there a way to know the usage, except for looking at the bills?
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict) is the API Documentation I referred to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation page you referenced is part of the [Cloud Machine Learning Engine API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/):

> An API to enable creating and using machine learning models.

That API is for using the product itself, it doesn't contain billing information for the product.

For billing info you want to look at [Cloud Billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/) and its [API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/getting-started):

> With this API, you can do any of the following.
>
> For billing accounts:
>
> ...
>
> - Get billing information for a project.

However from just a quick glance at the docs (I didn't use it yet) the API itself doesn't appear to directly provide the particular info you're looking for. But possible ways to get that info appear to be:

1. using [Billing Reports](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports):

> The Cloud Billing Reports page lets you view your Google Cloud
>   Platform (GCP) usage costs at a glance and discover and analyze
>   trends. The Reports page displays a chart that plots usage costs for
>   all projects linked to a billing account. To help you view the cost
>   trends that are important to you, you can select a data range, specify
>   a time range, configure the chart filters, and group by project,
>   product, or SKU.
>
> Billing reports can help you answer questions like these:
>
> - How is my current month's GCP spending trending?

2. [Export Billing Data to a File](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file):

> To access a detailed breakdown of your charges, you can export your
>   daily usage and cost estimates automatically to a CSV or JSON file
>   stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket you specify. You can then
>   access the data via the Cloud Storage API, CLI tool, or Google Cloud
>   Platform Console.

3. [Export Billing Data to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery):

> Billing export to BigQuery enables you to export your daily usage and
>   cost estimates automatically throughout the day to a BigQuery dataset
>   you specify. You can then access your billing data from BigQuery. You
>   can also use this export method to export data to a JSON file.

Comment: I thought that there would be some kind of way I was missing, cuz I saw that batch prediction API provides node hour usages: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#PredictionOutput